# Get name of particular/specific category name of root category in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In magento site I have multiple sub categories under the root category. I want name or id of only one particular/specific sub category. How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

To load particular category you can define the id like i have used 4

```
<?php $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>

$category_id = $this->getCategoryId();
$childrens = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                              ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', 4)
                 ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

?>